# How to trim white space for every element in JQ?

Tags: unix, trim, jq

I have the following simple JSON

```
json='[{"k1":" http://url", "k2":null, "k3":" v3", "k4":" v4"}]'
```

what I need is:

```
"http://url",null
```

(without a space before `v1` and `v2`)

What I have is:

```
echo $json | jq -c '.[] | .k1, .k2 ' | paste -d "," - -
```

How to get rid of the space in k1 and k2 values?

Comment: Do you have a jq new enough to have the `walk` function?

Comment: btw, `echo $json` is actually a bit buggy -- if you had a whitespace-surrounded `*` in your text it would be replaced with a list of filenames. Much better to `echo "$json"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have the latest `jq` version.

Comment: As of today, the latest release version doesn't have walk -- though it's available in trunk builds from git.

Comment: Are you happy when you replace all spaces like `echo "${json// }"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below will remove leading and trailing spaces in strings anywhere inside an arbitrarily complex JSON structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jq -cf

# Define walk function (standard library only for jq 1.6 and newer, currently unreleased)
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

walk(
  if type == "string" then
    (sub("^[[:space:]]+"; "") | sub("[[:space:]]+$"; ""))
  else . end
)
```

If one saves the above (e.g. in `trim-json`), and marks it executable (`chmod +x trim-json`), then `./trim-json <<<"$json"` with your given input emits:

```
[{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3","k4":"v4"}]
```

Similarly, with the updated input:

```
$ json='[{"k1":" http://url", "k2":null, "k3":" v3", "k4":" v4"}]'
$ ./trim-json <<<"$json"
[{"k1":"http://url","k2":null,"k3":"v3","k4":"v4"}]
```

Comment: Your solution works great, but there is a new requirement I forgot to mention - it must be able to work with `null` or empty string `''` or with urls. I have updated the question.

Comment: @AdamSiemion, ...I ran the existing code with the updated input. As shown in the edit, it worked perfectly. (Given such, I'm curious as to why you came back to me with a requested change).

Comment: @peak, thank you for the edit. (Most folks I'd ask to make suggestions in comments, but you have sufficient expertise on this topic that I've never been unhappy with one of your changes).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Yeah, I figured we're pretty much on the same wavelength.  In case you haven't noticed, the builtin def of walk has (today!) been modified to use keys_unsorted.  It would probably be a good idea to update the def here .... but that's definitely your call :-)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer -- I wasn't watching upstream closely enough to notice that, and not mutating order without explicit user intent is certainly an improvement.

Answer (score 13):

If the input is an array of JSON objects and if you're looking for a one-liner, then the following seems to meet your requirements:

```
jq '.[]|(.k1,.k2)|if type=="string" then gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$";"") else . end' | paste -d "," - -
```

With your input, this produces

```
"http://url",null
```

If you are flexible about how `null` is presented in the output, you might also consider an all-jq solution (i.e. without `paste`).  For example:

```
jq -r '.[]|[.k1,.k2]|map(if type=="string" then gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$";"") else . end)|@csv'
```

With your input, this produces:

```
"http://url",
```

Answer (score -1):

The example has a space in front of every value. For the case where you can simply remove the first (or N) characters of a string, then a simple map over range slicing works:

```
$ jq -c '.[] | map_values(.[1:]) | .k1,.k2' <<< "$json" | paste -d "," - -
"http://url",null
```

This approach has the benefit of being unpretentious and simple to understand.

Comment: This strips the first character, no matter *what* it is. If not certain that *every* string has a leading space, that's... a bit dangerous.